# Do I need to exclude all non-route actions from a Laravel controller middleware?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using **[controller middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#controller-middleware)** in my Laravel 5.2 app. According to the docs, to exclude specific actions from being handled by a middleware, I need to use the `except` array:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {

        // Exclude foo- and barAction from auth middleware
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => [
            'fooAction',
            'barAction',
        ]]);
    }
}
```

Of course, the total number of methods in a controller will almost always be greater than the number of methods linked to specific routes in **routes.php**. So except for the route-actions there will be others, dealing strictly with the logic - public or private methods.

**Do I need to exclude all those non-route actions from a middleware or excluding the route-actions is enough?**

EDIT:

I would say that the other, non-route methods - as they are not accessible from outside - don't need to be excluded from a middeware. The question is rather: is the middleware ran for them every time they are accessed? I wouldn't say so but it's nice to make sure.

Comment: I don't know Laravel particularly well, but what do you mean by a "non-route action"?  Surely "actions" are *only* those controller methods that might be invoked by a router?  To put it another way, I'd imagine that the middleware is invoked by the router when handling a route that invokes a relevant action; any other invocation of a controller method ought to bypass the middleware.

Comment: @eggyal That's my understanding as well, I'm just trying to make sure if that's correct. By "non-route actions", I mean controller methods which are not called by the router directly but provide extra logic. E.g. `showDashboard` method (route action) is called when the `/dashboard` URL is accessed. The `getDashboardFeed` method (non-route action) is in the controller to provide data for the called page.

Comment: Well, controllers that have methods like that probably violate the Single Responsibility Principle.  But anyway, I'm pretty sure those methods are not "actions" and therefore do not need to be explicitly excluded from your middleware configuration.  I'll take a look into the source and post an answer shortly.

Comment: You are using codeigniters principle. Laravel works in a different way. As long as a method isn't linked to routes, assigning middleware doesn't make any sense. You include/exclude them in middleware has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$this->middleware()` method is defined in [`Illuminate\Routing\Controller`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.39/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php): it merely saves its arguments in a protected property that is only accessed through a getter.

Other than in tests, that getter is *only* invoked in two places:

1. [`Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.39/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php#L182) (which handles the `route:list` Artisan command); and
2. [`Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.39/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php#L110)  (which dispatches routing calls to a controller).

Comment: Thanks very much for the code analysis. I think that settles it.